# How to add a new line to all digit and comma combination

Tags: notepad++

input data:

```
digit or digits comma digit or digits TEXT digit or digits comma digit or digits TEXT digit or digits comma digit or digits TEXT
```

result:

```
digit or digits comma digit or digits TEXT 

digit or digits comma digit or digits TEXT

digit or digits comma digit or digits TEXT
```

input example:

```
7,8 my input text with , as well as . as well as ; and " 7,9 my input text with , and . as well as ; " and 7,10 my input text with , and . as well as ; and "
```

output example:

```
7,8 my input text with , as well as . as well as ; and " 
7,9 my input text with , and . as well as ; " and 
7,10 my input text with , and . as well as ; and "
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: On what OS? MS uses Chr(13)Chr(10) (CR+LF), Linux just Chr(10) or LF, then there's Mac, EBCDIC, etc. Notepad++ implies Windows, but it also runs under wine on Linux.

Comment: It might be worth enabling "view > show symbol > show end of line" and looking for "CR LF" or just "LF". As @DrMoishePippik pointed out, there are different conventions. Notepad++ has end-of-line conversion under the edit menu

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\h)(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `\n`  OR `\r\n` depending on platform
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\h)     # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a space before
(?=\d)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have a digit after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]